How to display in jupyter an output of output widget as markdown?
In Jupyter i use to access OpenAI API with
import os
import openai

# Need an environmt variable for OPENAI. See https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

if openai.api_key is None:
raise ValueError("OpenAI API key is not set in environment variables.")

# Code from https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart?language-preference=python
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

def prompt(role, content):

# See https://platform.openai.com/docs/examples
roles = {
    "Friend" : "You are a friendly assistent",
    "Pettyman" : "You are a petty bigot dystopic assistent which answer very negative",
    "Summarizer" : "You will be provided with a message, and your task is to respond only three words."
}

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o", 
    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "{}".format(roles[role])},
        {"role": "user", "content": "{}".format(content)}
    ]
)

return "AI-"+role+ ": " +completion.choices[0].message.content+"\n"

promptContent = "Meaning of life as haiku"

print( prompt("Friend", promptContent) )

print( prompt("Pettyman", promptContent) )

to access the API of OpenAI.
To get the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY i use in terminal
echo "export OPENAI_API_KEY='openai-key'" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
echo $OPENAI_API_KEY

before i start jupyter with
jupyter lab

and code above. Then i use the code
from ipywidgets import widgets, Text, Button, HBox, Output
from IPython.display import display
import markdown

# Create a text widget
text_widget = Text(
    value='',
    placeholder='How can i help you?',   
    description='Prompt:',
)

# Create a button to submit the text
button = Button(description="Ask")

# Create output field
output = Output()

# Input Handler
def handle_input(b):
    output.clear_output()  # Clear previous output
    # Retrieve the value from the text widget
    prompt_value = text_widget.value
    # Set ai role an prompt
    result = prompt("Friend", prompt_value)

    # Unmark to print to log console
    # print(f'User: {prompt_value}')
    # print( result )

    # Output to widget (before solution)
    # output.append_stdout( f'User: {prompt_value}\n\n' )
    # output.append_stdout( result )

    # Output (with solution)
    with output:
        html_content = markdown.markdown(f"""User: {prompt_value}\n\n{result}""")
        display(widgets.HTML(html_content))

# Bind the button click to the function
button.on_click(handle_input)

# display all
display(HBox([text_widget, button]))
display(output)

In this context i need the jupyter widget too dynamically  get the openAI results. So how can i get the formatted markdown into the view of jupyter? This shows only the result of chatGPT, but not format it with markdown.

I think you only really get to the question at the end of your long post? I think you just want to know how to display the markdown in conjunction with ipywidgets? (Which you could have boiled down much further & included a complete MRE that I could fix to work and post as answer.)You should be able to direct the result to the markdown handler and then result of that to HTML(), see here for an example with code. Some more complex situations worked out here.

It is buried in a resource I linked to above, and so I'll highlight that you may also wish to look here They also may be more complex than you need as the first link may cover what you need.

Thanks for the hint. I followed the trail and found something in widget guide and realised it with the following lines: with output: html_content = markdown.markdown(f"""User: {prompt_value}\n\n{result}""")  display(widgets.HTML(html_content)). The with output: did the job to display the markdown after the entry..

Add Solution to code above. Solved.

It looks like you added that to the last code block but didn't update the last paragraph of your post to indicate that. Or add something below that indicating you solved it and integrated the solution in the code block just above.
